# How do I use jQuery .load method with the jsfiddle echo feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to test loading an AJAX response on jsfiddle.net and cant seem to figure out how to do it.

I'm calling `.load('/echo/html')` but I'm not sure how to pass in the data?

[**refer this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gVYJB/1/)

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.post-big").hide();

    $("div.expand").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parents('.post').load('/echo/html/');        
  });
});
```

Supporting HTML:

```
<div class="post">
  <div class="post-small">
    <div>Title</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div class="expand">expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-big"></div>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <div class="post-small">
    <div>Title</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div class="expand">expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-big"></div>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <div class="post-small">
    <div>Title</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div class="expand">expand</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-big"></div>
</div>
```

Supporting CSS:

```
.post {
    border: 1px solid #911;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was helpful to me, as was the answer.  I cleaned up the question a bit and added the code.  Code should be on SO as much as possible so questions and answers are self-contained, and only linking to third party sites for convenience.

Comment: Feel free to edit further or roll back if you don't like my changes, tho as you can already see it got another upvote :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply a second argument to the `.load` method, with an `html` property.

```
.load('/echo/html/', { html: 'Hello!' });
```

See the working example at [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gVYJB/2/)

In this demo, click on the text that says `expand` to trigger the load.

Answer (score 0):

the best thing that you can do is find an object where you want to attach code that simply trigger the function for the ajax call. like for instance

```
 $('button').click(function(){
      //do your ajax call here 
 });
```